# How to get port for node server in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have successfully deployed my react app to heroku - 
http://goku-portfolio.herokuapp.com
inside the website there is a page called contact(you can see that on the navigation bar) where form appears which contains three fields, data of which is stored in mongodb. Problem that I am facing is after that entering the data when I click on the submit button it is redirecting to port 2000 of localhost that is something I have mentioned in the contact.js file because of which the backend runs successfully on my machine, but does not on other machines. Also after submission of data I want the user to redirect back to the homepage (i.e. the above link) which is also not working. kindly tell me what changes i would have have to make so that my app stops using the localhost ports.
P.S. - node server is running on port 2000 (file name db.js)

db.js

```
    var express = require("express");
    var path = require("path");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var mongodb = require("mongodb");

    var dbConn = mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
      process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
        "mongodb://user:pass@ds019633.mlab.com:19633/heroku_dtl69fwz"
    );

    var app = express();
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
      );
      next();
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/contact.js")));
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      app.use(express.static("src/build"));
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "src", "build", "index.html"));
      });
    }
    app.post("/post-feedback", function(req, res) {
      console.log("something");
      dbConn.then(function(db) {
        delete req.body._id; // for safety reasons
        db.collection("feedbacks").insertOne(req.body);
      });
      res.write("<html><body>");
      res.write("Data received:\n" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
      res.write("You will be redirected shortly to the home page");
      res.write(
        "<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'https://goku-portfolio.herokuapp.com'; }, 3000);</script>"
      );
      res.write("</body></html>");
      res.send();
      //  res.sendFile("src/components/contact.js");
    });
    // app.get("/landingPage", function(req, res) {
    //   res.sendFile(__dirname + "src/components/contact.js");
    // });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0");
```

contact.js

```
      import React, { Component } from "react";

      class Contact extends Component {
        state = {};

        render() {
          return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row bg-contact justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <form
                    className="form-style"
                    method="POST"
                    action="http://localhost:2000/post-feedback"
                  >
                    <h1>Hola!</h1>
                    <h4>
                      {" "}
                      I am based out of Delhi and will be happy to assist you with
                      your request
                    </h4>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputEmail1"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                      ></input>
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "resume",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd src && npm install && npm run build"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
      "main": "index.js",
      "devDependencies": {},
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

I have changed the form action from https://localhost:3000/ to http://goku-portfolio.herokuapp.com/2000.

Comment: `action="http://localhost:2000/post-feedback"` - Nothing to do with Heroku or NodeJS. Your React code includes that **hardcoded** value. Remove it and add a *relative* path instead.

Comment: Please also note when asking questions in the future that the "tags" applied to your question are to be related to the subject of the question **only**, and **NOT** a representation  of the *entire stack* in use for your project. Nor should you include code other that the [**Minimal Amount Necessary to Demonstrate and Reproduce the Problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Whole code listings are really not appropriate for questions.

Comment: Note also that the actual port hosted will be `80`, which is actually the default http port ( or 443 for secure ). Your front end need not know this. The `process.env.PORT` thing is an *internal* binding for the process running on the server, which will *proxy* to the external address. Again, nothing your application need know. Simply `/post-feedback` or even `post-feedback` is probably enough.